# python find the largest number in a glob of filenames

Tags: python, tensorflow, pathlib

in a glob of filenames, I need to find the largest number.

*model_dir.glob('weights_epoch_*.tf.index')* returns a generator, but then what?

```
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_1.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_10.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_15.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_2.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_20.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_25.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_3.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_30.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_35.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_4.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_40.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_45.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_46.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_47.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_48.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_49.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_5.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_6.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_7.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_8.tf.index
/home/rac/amf9-horizon/weights_epoch_9.tf.index
```

Return int(49).

Comment: Then you iterate the generator, extract the numbers into a list and put that list into max() to get the largest number.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work.

```
file_names = model_dir.glob('weights_epoch_*.tf.index') 
largest = max(map(lambda x: int(re.findall(r'(\d+)\.tf\.index', x)[0]), file_names))
print(largest) # 49
```

Using built in `map` to apply regex on each of the `file_names` to extract the number and then call `max` to extract the largest.

---

#### Edit

Since the method returns an iterable of `PosixPath` you would need to cast the objects to `str` first:

For example

```
largest = max(map(lambda x: int(re.findall(r'(\d+)\.tf\.index', str(x))[0]), file_names))
```

Comment: , str(x)[0]   as it's PosixPath. Otherwise works.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably more elegant way but one approach is to split every path returned from glob with seperator "/", selecting last element and filter out every non numeric character. Then convert those strings to ints and find maximum. Something like this:

```
paths = glob('weights_epoch_*.tf.index')
max_epoch = max([int(''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, i.split("/")[-1]))) for i in paths])
```

Comment: you can drop the `[` and `]` in your comprehension since max works on generators.

Comment: str(i).split(),  as i is not str but a PosixPath. Otherwise works.